# Java Script alert R encountered a fatal error. This session was terminated

Tags: r, rstudio

I was using RStudio regularly and all was working smoothly..But recently my Windows crashed terribly and had to be restored to a previous time. Thereafter, when I opened RStudio, my project is not opening ad repeatedly showing the error **Java Script alert R encountered a fatal error. This session was terminated.**
I am sure I had closed Rstudio properly the time I had last used it before the Windows crash. Can anyone tell me how I could solve this problem(preferably without losing much data and work on RStudio)

Comment: I suppose you have re-installed RStudio after the WIndows crash, right?

Comment: I did not reinstall. Since i had restored it to the condition just a week back RStudio was already there. Is there any way I can just get my data/dataframes from the project since that is what is most important in that project

Comment: Did you save your files, history and `.Rdata`?

Comment: I had saved it on the computer itself. But since I had to restore it to a condition week back I guess it has something to do with that only. Probably some saved data/environ/history got corrupted

Comment: is there some way I could check any of these..especially the data..

Answer (score 2):

goto folder

```
c:/Users/yourUserName/AppData/Local/Rstudio-Desktop
```

And delete the file `history_database`. (For someone in linux, search the folder `.rstudio`) You will NOT lose your open files history or environment history. You may have to change your default folder, and open manually its .Rdata file, in order to get the last environment you saved. Ex.: `load(paste0(getwd(),"/.RData") )`

This solution can also work for Rstudio-server errors like:

```
ERROR session hadabend; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error<unnamed>::rInit(const rstudio::r::session::RInitInfo&)
```

See: https://community.rstudio.com/t/continuous-crash-on-rstudio-server/19302

These errors happen usually for having several untitled files open. After recovering, you may have to copy text of open files to empty files before saving.

Comment: I tried to delete the history file but not works, the https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/222227328/comments/226419348 is works for me.

Comment: from your not-answer below, I can see you have a different error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I installed a newer version of RStudio. It went away after I uninstalled the previous version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use few method but not works, finally get the solution via the [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/222227328/comments/226419348).

`<p>R encountered a fatal error.</p>The session was terminated.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case was related to Java-dependent package `xlxs`, removing it (form R terminal, no within RStudio) worked.

Answer (score -1):

(02-05-2020: Solution for Ubuntu 18.04)

After spending too many time, I found a solution:

- First remove r-base and others stuffs related to R

Remove files (with care) using:

`sudo find . -type f -name "*rstudio*"`
`sudo find . -type f -name "*.RData*"`
`sudo find . -type f -name "*.Rhistory*"`

You can use `-delete` to delete all files listed by the commands above using (**be careful**):

`sudo find . -type f -name "*rstudio*" -delete`

After removing eveything related to R and RStudio, restart the computer and install R using the following:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

After installing R, install RStudio by this link:

https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Obs.: I think removing R related files from `~.config` folder that really solved the problem.