# Rstudio encountered a Fatal Error on startup

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently upgraded R to 3.4.3 and RStudio to 1.1.383. After installation I got the `<p> R encountered a fatal error.</p>The session was terminated` bug.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start) on fixing startup problems, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642091/java-script-alert-r-encountered-a-fatal-error-this-session-was-terminated) similar question on stack overflow, and other RStudio support forums and none have been able to fix the error.

- My R version is running fine in the terminal and is the most recent version
- When I remove the ".rstudio-desktop", ".Rpofile", and ".Rhistory" files and start Rstudio it no longer uses my themes but now encounters a "Fatal Session" bug but when I restart my session it just keeps getting the bug.
- I've restarted my computer and re-installed Rstudio with no luck with anything.

I've included a diagnostic report [here](https://gist.github.com/mattmills49/511a6e7033d7b9f74e8ea4b278a06597); there are a decent number of errors but I'm not sure what they really mean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how did you upgrade to R?    Also, what OS are you on?    If on Mac OSX, make sure to install R from the maintained package file.    Either way, fully removing and reinstalling R would likely be helpful here

Comment: Maybe Ctrl + Click On RStudio and choose the right version of R.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I'm on Mac OS 10.13.2. What do you mean by "maintained package file"? I just downloaded the latest version of R (3.4.3) from the r-project website. My computer is picking up the new version in the Terminal and plain R.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting the R and Rstudio apps, the R frameworks, and the rstudio-desktop folder and reinstalling both apps.