# R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated. Error message after updating R and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, startup-error

I updated to R 4.3.0 and updated RStudio at the same time. After installing and upon opening an R project and before running any code, an error message immediately pops up "

R encountered a fatal error.

The session was terminated."

The same thing happens when I attempt to open RStudio directly and not through a project file.

I followed suggestions to remove .RData. I've also attempted to remove and reinstall as indicated on this [thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-encountered-a-fatal-error-the-session-was-terminated/6409). However, this didn't resolve the issue. I also saw a suggestion on that post to edit .Rprofile, but I either don't have this file or can't locate it. According to this [post](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/4726), that issue seems to have been resolved, so I'm not sure it is relevant to my issue.

I suspect it has something to do with R and not RStudio because I installed an old version of R 3.3.3 and RStudio did not produce the error message, but I need a newer version of R to run certain packages.

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801212/rstudio-encountered-a-fatal-error-on-startup). I've deleted and reinstalled R and RStudio a few times now and this hasn't fixed my problem. I'm not sure what they mean by "R Frameworks" and don't want to delete things I am not sure about.

Comment: To make sure the problem is with Rstudio, have you tried launching R from the terminal or another app launcher, directly? In a Unix system, it is as simple as typing `R` and `enter` in the terminal.

Comment: I can use R alone to run code without generating the "fatal error"; however I get a different error related to biomaRt package installation "caught segfault address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'". I've never seen this particular error before when installing packages that are not compatible versions, so I am not sure this is unrelated to my problem, though would easily believe it is a different issue.

Comment: FWIW, I did not figure out what was wrong, but switching to R 4.2.3 solved my problem.

Comment: Had an identical issue on Mac Ventura 13.5.2 With version 4.3.2